# Get meta tag content in jQuery

Tags: jquery, meta

I would like to get the meta content where pageDetails is my HTML page.

```
$(pageDetails).find('meta[name="biz-id"]').attr("content")
```

My HTML code is:

```
<meta name="biz-id" content="q6aDxTSK7njG7qWB1tSV5g">
```

Why my returned value is always empty?

Answer (score 8):

Have you already tried

```
var bizId = $("meta[name='biz-id']").attr("content");
```

In addition, in your query `$(pageDetails).find('meta[name="biz-id"]').attr("content")` it's not clear if you have `pageDetails` defined previously. Though this has already been noticed in another answer and the question seems to be resolved, just mentioning it here because of being informed that I shouln't have given this info in the comments below this answer but as comment below the OP.

Comment: Yes like I put in my question.

Comment: In your question you start with $(pageDetails).find(.., is pageDetails defined anywhere?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @mmichael Thanks for the input. I'd have left a comment to request clarification below the OP if this wouldn't have been already noted in an answer posted in the same minute as my comment. Just forgot to add the OP name before my comment so OP would have been informed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your quotes are backwards. This little sample sets the variable biz to what you have in content.

```
var biz = $("meta[name='biz-id']").attr("content");
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me [here](http://jsbin.com/jefofapeyotu/1/edit?html,console). Be careful to wait for the DOM to be ready.
With jQuery:

```
$(function() { /* ...code here.... */ });
```

Or maybe the problem is `pageDetails`. But we don't have this part of the code. What you could/should do is probably:

```
var $pageDetails = $('head');
```

Hope this helped.

NOTE : the `$` before `pageDetails` is just here to know that it's a jQuery object. It's quite a good practice I think.